# "file not found" on travis-ci when running pytest from tox using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, travis-ci, pytest, tox

I'm trying to run my tests throught travis-ci, but i receive
"file not found tests" error. When i run local with same command everything is ok, but in travis i receive this error. I think its because tests folder which in root of my project located somewhere in other directory - in directory where travis copy github repo.

I try this settings in `tox.ini` but none of whem help:

```
commands = py.test $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/tests {posargs}

passenv = TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR
commands = py.test $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/tests {posargs}

commands = py.test {env:TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:.}/tests {posargs}
```

My setup:

My `.travis.yml`

```
sudo: required

language: python

services:
  - docker

script:
  - docker-compose run tox
```

My `docker compose file`

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  tox:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ".:/src:ro"
```

My `tox.ini`

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27}-{django18,django19,django110,django111},{py35}-{django18,django19,django110,django111,django20}
skipsdist = {env:TOXBUILD:false}

[testenv]
sitepackages = False
deps=
    pytest==2.9.2
    pytest-capturelog==0.7
    pytest-django==2.9.1
    psycopg2==2.7.3.2
    pytest-pep8==1.0.6
    freezegun==0.3.9
    pytz==2017.3

    django18: Django>=1.8,<1.9
    django19: Django>=1.9,<1.10
    django110: Django>=1.10,<1.11
    django111: Django>=1.11,<2.0
    django20: Django>=2.0,<2.1
commands = py.test tests {posargs}
```

My `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
addopts=-l -q --capture=no
pep8ignore = E501
norecursedirs = .robe .idea
python_files = tests.py test_*.py
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_app.settings
```

My `dockerfile`:

```
FROM themattrix/tox
```

Comment: Your tox.ini call is

    ``py.test test {posargs}``

not test-->s<--

Comment: make mistake while copy, my actual value was tests.

Comment: I have no answer, but I think you can debug this by getting more info, e.g. call  tox and pytest with -vvv and if needed output more info like pwd and ls to see why dir is not found (e.g. in commands section of tox.ini).