# Why is my Travis CI build failing with "File Not Found" errors when those files exist?

Tags: travis-ci, pytest

**I'm trying to determine why [my Travis CI build job](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100) is failing with "File Not Found" errors like [the one below](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100#L291), despite the files having absolute paths and almost certainly existing in the specified location:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/travis/build/Lx/python-rosteron/test/HTML/login.html'
```

---

The job in question is [Travis CI Job #1.1 for Lx/python-rosteron](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100), which clearly shows:

- [on line 160](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100#L160), [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Lx/python-rosteron) being cloned into a relative path of `Lx/python-rosteron`:

  ```
  $ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/Lx/python-rosteron.git Lx/python-rosteron
  ```
- [on line 168](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100#L168), that directory becoming the current directory:

  ```
  $ cd Lx/python-rosteron
  ```
- [on line 169](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100#L169), [tree `e402d3d`](https://github.com/Lx/python-rosteron/tree/e402d3dca365f9b5a3145b65b4fb28515177b581) being checked out—which [demonstrably](https://github.com/Lx/python-rosteron/blob/e402d3dca365f9b5a3145b65b4fb28515177b581/test/html/login.html) shows that `./test/HTML/login.html` would now exist:

  ```
  $ git checkout -qf e402d3dca365f9b5a3145b65b4fb28515177b581
  ```
- [on line 210](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100#L210), the current directory proving to have an absolute path of `/home/travis/build/Lx/python-rosteron`, meaning `/home/travis/build/Lx/python-rosteron/test/HTML/login.html` must exist:

  ```
  Installing MechanicalSoup-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl to /home/travis/build/Lx/python-rosteron/.eggs
  ```
- and [on line 291](https://travis-ci.org/Lx/python-rosteron/jobs/544101100#L291), the allegation that this file does **not** exist:

  ```
  E       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/travis/build/Lx/python-rosteron/test/HTML/login.html'
  ```

---

## What I've tried

- Extensively trawling through the failed build log, as shown above, to no avail.
- Restarting the build in case it was some transient error, which resulted in no change.
- Searching Stack Overflow for similar questions, yielding these results:

  - [TravisCI with pytest and numpy.load(): File not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53719350/4877269)—[resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719350/travisci-with-pytest-and-numpy-load-file-not-found#comment94292694_53719350) was to use absolute paths, which doesn't help here as absolute paths are already in use.
  - [“file not found” on travis-ci when running pytest from tox using docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48018935/4877269)—no resolution offered.
  - [My Travis keeps erroring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080856/4877269)—[“resolution”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080856/my-travis-keeps-erroring#comment37163009_24080856) was to contact Travis CI Support if the OP was a Travis Pro customer, which I'm not.

---

**Can anyone see any other reason that the checked-out files, being referenced by absolute paths, should not exist?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by case sensitivity.

- The directory name was `html`.
- The test was looking for a directory named `HTML`.
- I somehow failed to notice this for a very long time.

Today I also learned that my Mac system, despite being UNIX-based, has a case-insensitive file system.  Otherwise I would have picked this cause up a long time ago.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time.  Thank you.